# Возможно ли извлечь параметр из JS объекта без копирования, удалив его в самом объекте?

Tags: javascript, объекты, move

Нужно сделать своего рода `move` из объекта в переменную, но только чтобы не копировать весь параметр объекта который может быть весьма большим вложенным объектом.
Например:

```
let obj = {key1: val, key2: {/*very big data here*/}};
let data = SomeMoveFunction(obj, "key2");

// result
console.log(data); // Object {/*very big data here*/}
console.log(obj); // Object {key1: val}
```

Возможно ли это без копирования?

Comment: Что значит без копирования? И без копирования куда...

Comment: Удалить можно, возвращать можно, но насчет не копирования сомневаюсь. Это что-то на уровне плюсов и указателей. Тут насколько я знаю таких возможностей нету.

Comment: @SwaD имеется ввиду - переместить не значение, а само свойство как новую переменную.

Comment: При работе с объектами всегда ссылка копируется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, вы хотите скопировать значение в переменную и удалить это свойство у объекта. Для удаления можно использовать оператор [delete](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_remove_property_object.asp).

```js
function SomeMoveFunction(obj, key) {
  if (obj[key]) {
    let res = obj[key]
    delete obj[key]
    return res
  }
  return undefined
}
```

Comment: Неправильно поняли. `let res = obj[key]` делает именно то, что автору не нужно.

Comment: @eccs0103 то есть автор хочет создать ссылку на поле объекта, a затем удалить поле, но не его содержимое?

Comment: Если `obj[key]` объект, а не примитив, то `res` примет на него ссылку, и после удаления самого объекта вернёт из функции пустой объект. Так что это не то. Про `delete` осведомлён, благодарю.

Comment: Скорее не удалить поле, а отсоединить от объекта.

Comment: @Iceman, вы не правы он не вернёт пустой объект, для проверки запустите следующий код: `const obj1 = {
    a: "1111",
    b: {a: 11, b: 12},
    c: {a: 5, b: 6}
}

const copy = obj1.b
delete obj1.b
console.log(copy)
console.log(obj1.b)
`

Comment: `res` примет ссылку на значение поля и как раз никакого копирования не произойдёт

Comment: Честно, немного в шоке. Объект всё-таки возвращается, а оригинальный становится `undefined`... Почему-то был уверен, что ссылка тоже "обнулится". Благодарю

Comment: @Iceman как я понял, это происходит из-за того что `delete` удаляет только ключ, а его содержимое потом удаляет **garbage collector**.  Но если где-то остается ссылка на значение (в данном случае в res), то значение ещё можно получить и GC его не удаляет.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить вот такой вариант с деструктурирующим копированием

```js
let obj = {key1: 'val', key2: {a: 1, b: 2}};
let data = SomeMoveFunction(obj, "key2");

function SomeMoveFunction(inObj, key) {
  let { [key]: data } = inObj;
  delete inObj[key];
  return data;
}

console.log(data)
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: А деструктуризация разве не копирует значение? Я не уверен, могу ошибаться.

Comment: @eccs0103 Без коприрования не обойтись в явном виде. Сначала надо сохранить, потому удалить. "переключить" не выйдет